# change wp dropdown users - filter by user role

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to customize the `wp_dropdown_users` function:

```
<form method="post" >
 <?php foreach ($_POST as $key => $val): ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 <?php wp_dropdown_users(array('selected' => ($_POST['user'] ? : get_current_user_id()))); ?>
  <input type="submit" value="go" />
 </form>
```

The dropdown-field should only list all users with role `"device" ('role' => 'device')`.
How can I realize it? Anyone please help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the accepted answer worked at one point, but it doesn't seem to anymore. Wordpress filters out the 'role' argument before it reaches the query. I've modified it a bit due to that:

```
$users_with_role = implode(",", get_users ( array ( 'fields' => 'id', 'role' => 'customer' ) ) );

wp_dropdown_users(array(
    'selected' => ($_POST['user'] ? :    get_current_user_id()),
    'include_selected' => true,
    'include' => $users_with_role
));
```

Comment: I believe this still works, but I'll edit it if someone finds it doesn't anymore since this is pretty old now. And I don't think I understood how accepted answers worked as this doesn't actually have an accepted answer. 

Answer (score 0):

Even though it isn't documented in the `wp_dropdown_users` function you can pass the 'role' parameter in args. You can pass any argument accepted by `WP_User_Query::prepare_query()`.

So for example `echo wp_dropdown_users( array( 'role' => 'administrator' ) );` will display a dropdown of users with the administrator role. In your case, you'd have

```
<?php echo wp_dropdown_users(
    array(
        'selected' => ($_POST['user'] ? :    get_current_user_id()),
        'role' => 'device'
    )
); ?>
```

This assumes you have users with the role 'device' which isn't default. Don't forget to echo. `wp_dropdown_users` doesn't display anything without it.

Comment: Thanks a lot James. This helps me!

Comment: Does not work for me (WP 4.5) - wordpres filters arguments

Answer (score 0):

create filter:

```
function filter_wp_dropdown_users_args($query_args) {
    $query_args['role'] = 'device';
    return $query_args;
}
```

and use it:

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users_args', 'filter_wp_dropdown_users_args');
wp_dropdown_users();
remove_filter('wp_dropdown_users_args', 'filter_wp_dropdown_users_args');
```